# Inconsistent Accessibility error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I don't think there is anything wrong with this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace mynamespace
{
    public class DAOFolder
    {
        public List<DAOFilemeta> filemetas { get; set; }
        public string folder_id { get; set; }
        public string localFolder { get; set; }
        public string serverFolder { get; set; }
        public bool has_favourites_y_n { get; set; }

        public DAOFolder()
        {
            if (filemetas == null) filemetas = new List<DAOFilemeta>();
        }

        public void setByKey(String key, object value)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case "folder_id":           folder_id = (string)value; break;
                case "localFolder":         localFolder = (string)value; break;
                case "serverFolder":        serverFolder = (string)value; break;
                case "has_favourites_y_n":  has_favourites_y_n = (bool)value; break;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

but I am getting `Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<mynamespace.DAOFilemeta>' is less accessible than property 'mynamespace.DAOFolder.filemetas'` does anyone know why?

Is this a bug in VS2013?

Comment: Can we see the code for DAOFileMeta?

Comment: What's the accessibility of `DAOFilemeta`?

Comment: I'm guessing `DAOFilemeta` is internal (or not public somehow), which would mean the compiler is correct.

Comment: it depends on your DAOFilemeta accessible type. If its less accessible than DAOFolder its expected.

Comment: ahh thank you . I have the flu I think I am drowsy :-) ty